# Pandas не видит excel таблицу

Tags: python, pandas, excel

Есть шаблонная таблица для выгрузки товаров в Ozon ([ссылка на шаблонную таблицу](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1udrbqBNDTSonejtnxq8x29NIw1yGaPmY/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=104271521936691806904&rtpof=true&sd=true)). При попытке ее прочитать не выдаются никакие данные.

```
import pandas as pd

template_df = pd.read_excel('template.xlsx')

print(template_df)
```

На выходе это:

```
     Unnamed: 0  ...                                        Unnamed: 51
0           NaN  ...  3917231009 - Прочие трубы, трубки и шланги, же...
1           NaN  ...                    8414592000 - Вентиляторы осевые
2           NaN  ...  8471800000 - Usb концентратор (хаб), для подкл...
```

Comment: ну а чем вам это не данные?

Comment: @strawdog нужно колонки увидеть и их порядок, а это бред сивой кобылы какой то

Comment: если вы ожидали увидеть вывод как в Excel, то понятное дело, что для вас это "бред сивой кобылы".

Comment: @ZxNuClear как увидеть колонки то? Признаю что может быть глупый вопрос, но рассчитываю на понимание

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну во первых, при открытии укажите лист, с которым хотите работать

```
df = pd.read_excel('template.xlsx', sheet_name='Шаблон')
```

чтобы получить список имен столбцов есть много способов, например использовать `.tolist()`

```
print(df.columns.values.tolist())
```

вывод:

```
['№', 'Артикул*', 'Название товара', 'Цена, руб.*', 'Цена до скидки, руб.', 'НДС, %*', 'Включить продвижение', 'Ozon ID', 'Штрихкод (Серийный номер / EAN)', 'Вес в упаковке, г*', 'Ширина упаковки, мм*', 'Высота упаковки, мм*', 'Длина упаковки, мм*', 'Ссылка на главное фото*', 'Ссылки на дополнительные фото', 'Ссылки на фото 360', 'Артикул фото', 'Бренд*', 'Название модели (для объединения в одну карточку)*', 'Макс. выходная мощность, Вт', 'Количество выходных разъемов', 'Количество в упаковке, шт', 'Цвет товара', 'Комплектация зарядного устройства', 'Разъем на кабеле', 'Гарантийный срок*', 'Тип*', 'Аннотация', 'Партномер', 'Размеры, мм', 'Вес товара, г', 'Комплектация', 'Страна-изготовитель', 'Платформа', 'Выходной коннектор', 'Номинальное (входное) напряжение', 'Конструктивные особенности', 'Входное напряжение, В', 'Назначение', 'Выходное напряжение, В', 'Список совместимых устройств', 'Макс. выходной ток, А', 'Длина кабеля, м', 'Быстрая зарядка', 'Rich-контент JSON', 'Количество заводских упаковок', 'Стандарт быстрой зарядки', 'Макс. входное напряжение, В', 'Мин. входное напряжение, В', 'Разъем на блоке', 'Рекомендовано для устройств', 'ТН ВЭД коды ЕАЭС', 'Ключевые слова', 'Название серии', 'HS-код', 'Ошибка', 'Предупреждение']
```

Comment: Вчера так пробовал, почему то не работало, большое спасибо!